# Javascript variables once : Performance vs Readability

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, ternary

I was wondering about performances in Javascript vs Readability. We used to declare variables used only once in the function to get our code the most readable possible.

For example we have this code using the npm package MySQL which sanitize and execute a query with a string and an object parameter :

```js
function doSomething ( somethingId = null ) {
    if ( !somethingId ) return false
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM something WHERE somethingId = :somethingId"
    const params = { somethingId }
    return db.query(sql, params)
}
```

So I would like to minify the code to obtain something like this :

```js
function doSomething ( somethingId = null ) {
    return ( !somethingId )
        ? false
        : db.query("SELECT * FROM something WHERE somethingId = :somethingId", { somethingId })
}
```

The point is I would like to know if this change something in terms of performance ? Because I would think declaring variable has a cost and bypassing this will be faster ... But we will lose in readability ...

What do you think ?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this and found it to be a bottleneck that *requires* optimisation? I'd assume not. And you'll probably never find that this will ever *require* any sort of optimisation…

Comment: "Because I would think declaring variable has a cost" probably not. In [a sea of nodes](https://darksi.de/d.sea-of-nodes/), there's not much difference between a constant variable read only once and an expression. And even if it "had a cost", that cost would be pretty small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always prioritize readability, as the kind of performance gains you are describing are almost insignificant.

The problem with readability is that folk all too easily focus on the minutia, such as extra variables, whitespace etc and in the process miss the elephant in the room. Readability is just one component of code quality. And as Thom Holwerda put it, quality can be expressed as being inversely proportional to the number of WTFs/minute:

[image]

Comment: Ah ah +1 for the picture, i know the gain of performance is ridiculous but in fact we use so many functions like this I think if we could gain 0.001s it's 1sec of gain for 1000 requests ... For only one function it could be laughable but if you chain a lot of functions it could be important...